# Android Studio SVG image turns into black. Inscape export

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, svg

dear stack'ers.  I have a button with gradient, that turns into black in Android Studio. My friend made images for me, so I need your help to make them look good. I use Inscape to check if the image is bad, but in Inscape everything is ok.
[Inscape version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USqQg.png)

When I add image in Android Studio, some parts of it become black.

[Android studio version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYGud.png)

I found exactly a "problem part" - it was a gradient

```
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M184.391 56.2773C171.375 55.7715 152.471 55.2658 138.959 55.5018C118.282 56.8843 97.2143 56.9854 75.686 56.5808C71.3861 56.3704 67.0764 56.7336 62.8825 57.6598C53.9335 56.2657 44.8887 55.4994 35.8214 55.3669C27.1675 55.6704 17.8753 49.3312 14.0094 43.5652C17.5561 49.7021 27.203 57.0529 36.247 56.6482C45.3574 56.1959 54.4846 57.1525 63.2727 59.4807C67.3133 58.0972 71.617 57.5455 75.8988 57.8621C97.1788 58.3005 117.962 57.8621 138.533 56.311C151.833 56.0413 171.021 57.0529 183.966 57.5924C189.292 56.2066 194.314 53.9224 198.791 50.8485C200.314 49.709 201.684 48.3953 202.87 46.9371C203.553 46.0772 204.158 45.1634 204.678 44.2059C204.302 44.8214 203.875 45.4077 203.402 45.9593C202.214 47.3756 200.844 48.6444 199.323 49.7358C194.79 52.7054 189.732 54.8755 184.391 56.1424V56.2773Z" fill="url(#paint33_radial_190_7737)"/>
```

So, help me please, how do I export correctly from Inscape OR ANY OTHER FREE SVG-EDITOR to import in Android Studio correctly.

Thanks for answer :3.

Comment: Without seeing the code is impossible to say but I would guess the gradient used has some sort of transparency. If this is the case you may try to add a similar shape filled white underneath.

Comment: Is Inscape on te Android or different machine?  Most likely it is the driver in Android that is causing issue and not the app.  See if there are new drivers for Android or updates for the kernel.

Comment: Inscape on PC. Android studio is on PC to. But it displays incorrectly.